# The creation of Superman? (Bone fracture)

Tags: biology, hard-science, super-powers

This question asks for hard science. All answers to this question should be backed up by equations, empirical evidence, scientific papers, other citations, etc. Answers that do not satisfy this requirement might be removed. See the tag description for more information.

The first article: [The creation of Superman? ( skeleton )](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/164638/the-creation-of-superman-skeleton)

I'm going to create a series of questions devoted to the peculiarities of the creation of a scientifically-based Superman.

My question is: Is it possible to create a certain structure (inside or on the surface of the bones) in which during the fracture, the bones will "automatically" adjust to avoid incorrectly fused fracture? That is, to do something so that the bones are always fused correctly, self-aligning.

Comment: There's a "buzz term" here: anti-fragile. Some things are harmed by small challenges to their structure. But others are induced to become stronger, at least to some extent. Possibly searches on this term will be useful.

Comment: How perfect does this alignment need to be?

Comment: The more the better. But in principle, the bone after a fracture should automatically (independently ) adjust. That is, to put a tire so that the fracture does not shift, you do not need this system ( at the bottom is my personal version ) itself aligns and holds the bone.
( if the fracture is displaced, it uses a "lever" to align it back )

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple...

If we assume that this superman is not human, or even of Terran origin regardless of however human he looks, this opens up a lot of possibilities... such as the composition of his bones.

If this superman's bones were made from some strong, ductile substance,  perhaps some sort of metal, his bones would not break except under stresses that would most likely tear part of the limb off entirely, they would merely bend.

So wouldn't that leave him with a bent limb?   Yes and no.  Certainly the limb would be bent, but a bone need not be considered to be a static structure.   Human bones can be remodelled by biological processes to allow for the stresses they must endure,  so it is entirely reasonable to expect that the alien Superman's bones could be remodeled too.  It is also reasonable to expect that the body could detect a bent bone, and actively bend it back to where it should be without the necessity for medical intervention.

So... TL,DR: This superman's bones wouldn't break, they would bend, and depending on the speed of his metabolism, bent bones would unbend themselves over the course of days to months or even years.

Finally, the bone being merely bent, a damaged limb would have reduced utility,  but wouldn't be as unusable as a limb with a broken bone.

Comment: firstly, this description of a more modified skeleton is “unreasonable" because you did not instill biological features, whereby the bones should be strong and at the same time have such a level of tensile elongation.
See simple arguments and scientific facts. Secondly, look at my last article, what you said more about it.
Thirdly, I’m talking about creating a genetically modified person (only this !!! No implants, nanorobots, magic, etc., just biological suggestions!)

Comment: @FrenchThompson Monty doesn't mention any implants, nanorobots, or magic. The bones he describes *are* purely biological. Your objections seem unreasonable.

Comment: @F1Krazy I think the absence of what exactly the bone is made of is the OP's problem. "Some strong and ductile material" could be anything, but does not mean it is biological. It also means there is no way we can gauge the effectiveness of the regenerative method to restore bent bone as it depends on the material how much time and effort this will take for the body. A clearer explanation of how deep this explanation needs to go is necessary from the OP.

Comment: The bones I describe are the natural support structure of an alien (or perhaps genetically engineered) being.  They may be made from any substance that is ductile... Gold would be an extreme example, though impractical given its density and softness.  A particularly ductile variety of stainless steel might work, as might a ductile aluminum or magnesium alloy.  The point is that vertebrates' Calcium Carbonate bones are strong but brittle, and break under strain, while a ductile substance would bend, *not* break, and having been bent, could naturally *un*bend.

Comment: What needs to be improved or added in the human body to prevent improperly healed fractures (if the bones have already broken)?

Comment: This question asks for hard science. All answers to this question should be backed up by equations, empirical evidence, scientific papers, other citations, etc. Answers that do not satisfy this requirement might be removed. See the tag description for more information. therefore no aliens, magic, aliens, and cybernetics. Let's write a case.